# Display Login form in Cms Page in Magento 2?

Tags: widget, content-management-system, block, magento2

how can i display the login form on the CMS page in Magento 2?
I want add it in a Block. This was the way for Magento 1.x

> {{block type="customer/login" template="persistent/customer/form/login.phtml"}}

Answer (score 4):

You can use below structure to resolve your problem.

**Syntax**

```
{{block class="[BlockClassFullName]" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YoutTemplateFile.location].phtml"}}
```

**Example:**

```
{{block class="Magento\Bannerslider\Block\Slideshow" template="Magento_Bannerslider::bannerslider.phtml"}}
```

**Code for you**

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml"}}
```

Comment: In my case it must bee :
<{{block class="\Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" template="Magento_Customer_Block_Form_Login::login.phtml"}}

ist this correct?

Comment: I think it should be `{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml"}}` can you please try this.